# How to make a blink shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I want my gameobject Fade from red to white,and repeatedly.

so i create one shader,like this , but i'm not sure how to turn red then white,and repeatedly.

[image]

Comment: a) your image is barely readable ;) b) fade != blink in my understanding .. you probably want some sinus value based on the time and then blend between white and red using that sinus factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking to do. It is pretty straight forward you're just blending between two colors and controlling the opacity with the sine of time.

[image: Shader Graph Example]

An additional note you can alter the behavior of the blink by replacing the sine node with any of the wave nodes (E.g square wave for a strobe effect).